# Wordpress get all category from a post slug via my sql

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I have a custom table that is used to track the access to a website.
The table is as following:

date,post_slug,user

I want to create a query (mysql) that from this table add a 4th column containing all the categories of the post.

I don't want to create a new row for each category just a row with all the categories added to each row of this table.

The informations should be stored in wp_term_relationship and wp_terms but I don't know how to create just one row and not n rows for each category

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Main thing you should do is `group by wp_posts.id`. This command merges all equal `id` to one row. Now, you should use `group_concat( FIELDNAME )` to getting all desire fields in one column.

You need category names or category id?

If you wish have category name:

```
  SELECT tbl.*,GROUP_CONCAT(term.name) FROM
  YOURTABLE as tbl
  left join wp_posts as p
  on p.post_name = tbl.post_slug
  left join wp_term_relationships as rels
  on rels.object_id = p.ID
  left JOIN wp_term_taxonomy as tx
  on tx.term_taxonomy_id = rels.term_taxonomy_id
  left join wp_terms as term
  on term.term_id = tx.term_id
  where tx.taxonomy = "category"
  group by p.ID
```

If you need category id:

```
 SELECT tbl.*,GROUP_CONCAT(tx.term_taxonomy_id) FROM
 YOURTABLE as tbl
 left join wp_posts as p
 on p.post_name = tbl.post_slug
 left join wp_term_relationships as rels
 on rels.object_id = p.ID
 left JOIN wp_term_taxonomy as tx
 on tx.term_taxonomy_id = rels.term_taxonomy_id
 -- left join wp_terms as term
 -- on term.term_id = tx.term_id
 where tx.taxonomy = "category"
 group by p.ID
```

Note:

- `YOURTABLE` is your 3-column table.
- If you want get all tags, just edit `where tx.taxonomy = "category"` to `where tx.taxonomy = "post_tag"`
- If you are using custom post types and you want wordpress custom post types tags or categories, add `and p.post_type ="YOURPOSTTYPE"` after `where ..` line.

Comment: It worked, I just added DISTINCT on term.name of GROUP_CONTACT otherwise was generating n times the same group

Comment: I was trying to do this exact thing, and tried like 8 other examples that weren't quite right, and finally found this perfect code that worked on the first try. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, this only gets me one taxonomy (though it does so perfectly). I have a custom post type with many taxonomies. 

How would I get one row where a post has multiple columns, one for each taxonomy name, where the row value is a GROUP_CONCAT list of the term names for that taxonomy? Would that require a PIVOT on a subquery?